# Generic container interface parameterized by specific generic contained interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, containers, restriction

**The goal :**

To create generic interface that is parameterized by type that implements another specific generic interface.

**Problem :**

I'm trying to write the following related interfaces in C# and I can't decide if what I'm trying to do is possible or not.

```
public interface IVersion<T>
{
    IVersionManager<IVersion<T>> Parent { get; }
    // various other methods
}

public interface IVersionManager<T> where T : IVersion<T>
{
    IReadOnlyList<T> Versions { get; }
    T Current { get; }
    void AddVersion(T version);
    // various other methods
}
```

Unfortunately Visual Studio seems to find the self reference (`IVersionManager<IVersion<T>>`) in the `IVersion<T>` interface rather offensive.

It throws the following error:

> The type '`IVersion<T>`' must be convertible to '`IVersion<IVersion<T>>`'
>   in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic interface
>   '`IVersionManager<T>`'

That makes it sound as if it's circular but I don't think it actually is.

It makes sense to me. Am I crazy? Is this possible? I just want the child version to be able to reference it's parent manager.

Google search hasn't turned up anything. I suspect that perhaps I just don't know how to phrase the question.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the use of different variable names. My use of T everywhere was hiding the fact that I do have a circular reference in IVersionManager. hmm....

Comment: What is `T` supposed to represent in your `IVersion` interface? Is it supposed to be the manager, a different version, or something else?

Comment: Frankly it doesn't really matter. Say it's Strings or Integers.

Comment: You'll want to avoid designing cycles like that into your classes--they will bite you in no time.

Comment: Ok, that helps, so the answers about constraining the `T` on the `IVersion` interface don't apply then.

Comment: @PeterRitchie What cycles would those be?

Comment: A cycle is a circular reference.  Much of the documentation on drawbacks refers to "cycles".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suppose it should be:

```
public interface IVersion<T>
{
    IVersionManager<T> Parent { get; }
    // various other methods
}

public interface IVersionManager<T>
{
    IReadOnlyList<IVersion<T>> Versions { get; }
    IVersion<T> Current { get; }
    void AddVersion(IVersion<T> version);
    // various other methods
}
```

There is no need to define a `where` constraints to achieve type safety. But the downside is that your `VersionManagers` are defined not by the actual `Version<T>` type but by the type `T` used to define `Version<T>`.

---

I don't know about any real way to achieve both the ability to define `IVersion's` generic parameter and to make `IVersionManager` generic on `IVersion` using only one generic parameter.

So, to achieve true "genericness" on `IVersion` implementers you'll have to use more complex types and restrictions:

```
public interface IVersion<T>
{
    IVersionManager<T> Parent { get; }
    // various other methods
}

public interface IVersionManager<TVersion, T> 
    where TVersion : IVersion<T>
{
    IReadOnlyList<TVersion> Versions { get; }
    TVersion Current { get; }
    void AddVersion(TVersion version);
    // various other methods
}
```

It is a bit superfluous and unwieldy, but allows to create more specified `VersionManagers`, that are truly generic on `IVersion` implementers.

Comment: Well, yes the downside of this is that it doesn't define the Version type any longer...

Comment: Indeed. I'll have to think about that. I can see now that I was being silly though.

Comment: It's a bit silly to specify it twice but it does the job and it makes sure that an IVersion implementing type is used. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to avoid placing a constraint on IVersion, you could expand the constraint instead on the IVersionManager.  It's a bit clunky however, since you have to pass the type for T2 twice

```
public interface IVersion<T>
{
    IVersionManager<IVersion<T>, T> Parent { get; }
}

public interface IVersionManager<T, T2> where T : IVersion<T2>
{
    IReadOnlyList<T2> Versions { get; }
    T2 Current { get; }
    void AddVersion(T2 version);
    // various other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get it to *compile* by adding the restriction to `Version<T>`:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IVersion<T> where T:IVersion<T>   // <----- add restriction here
{
    IVersionManager<T> Parent { get; }  // <--- change generic type here
    // various other methods
}

public interface IVersionManager<T> where T : IVersion<T>
{
    IReadOnlyList<T> Versions { get; }  
    T Current { get; }
    void AddVersion(T version);
    // various other methods
}
```

Whether it's *right* or not is up to you to determine...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constraint to `T` in `IVersion`:

```
public interface IVersion<T> where T : IVersion<T>
{
    IVersionManager<T> Parent { get; }
    // various other methods
}
```